# R mapply function running slowly

Tags: r, memory, data.table, memory-efficient, mapply

I'm working on calculating item statistics for a series of multiple choice exams. I've got a solution using mapply that technically works, but it takes a few hours to calculate one of the more complicated statistics. The first dataset that I have is one that includes a separate row for every question that every student answered for every assessment.

```
df <- data.frame(c(rep("s1", 5), rep("s2", 5), rep("s3", 5),rep("s4", 5)),"a1", c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5"), c(1, 0), 1)

colnames(df) <- c("student", "assessment", "item", "score", "points.possible")
```

The first step that I do (and only do once) is to create a table of all unique items. In this case, that would be simple, as there's only one assessment and 5 items.

```
unique <- subset(df[,c("assessment", "item")], !duplicated(df[,c("assessment", "item")]))
```

I then need to calculate a statistic for each one of these items. However, the tricky part is that the calculations requires calculating the overall scores that students got on the entire assessment. Here's the function I wrote to do that.

```
fun1 <- function(a.id, i.id) {
  # subset original dataframe for just one assessment
  subsetdf <- df[df$assessment == a.id,]

  # generate list of students that got the item right and wrong
  correct <- subsetdf$student[subsetdf$item==i.id & subsetdf$score==1]
  wrong <- subsetdf$student[subsetdf$item==i.id & subsetdf$score==0]

  # scores by student
  scores <- aggregate(score ~ student, data=subsetdf,sum)/aggregate(points.possible ~ student, data=subsetdf, sum)  

  # average scores for students that got item right/wrong
  x.1 <- sum(subsetdf$score[subsetdf$student %in% correct])/sum(subsetdf$points.possible[subsetdf$student %in% correct])
  x.0 <- sum(subsetdf$score[subsetdf$student %in% wrong])/sum(subsetdf$points.possible[subsetdf$student %in% wrong])

  # percent of students that got item right
  p <- length(correct)/(length(correct)+length(wrong))

  # final stat calculation
  r <- ((x.1-x.0)*sqrt(p*(1-p)))/sd(scores[,2])
  print(r)
}
```

I then used mapply to loop this function over the entire original dataset while using the smaller dataset for the inputs.

```
unique$r <- mapply(fun1, unique$assessment, unique$item)
```

I was happy that I was able to get it to work, but when I do it with the larger datasets (~7 million rows for "df", ~2000 rows for "unique), it takes quite a while (several hours). Any tips on other ways to tackle this problem that are more efficient? I've learned that one problem is that my function creates a copy of the original large dataset every time it loops through, but I don't know how to do the problem without that.

I still consider myself a beginner for this kind of usage for R, so any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thoughts: (1) don't subset the entire `df`, use `suba <- df$assessment == a.id`, `subi <- df$item == i.id`, and perhaps (if truly binary) `subs <- df$score == 0`, and reuse the you-know-what out of those logical vectors on `df`; (2) same for storing the list of `...$student %in% correct`, no need to recalc it; (3) if the data is truly large, perhaps `data.table`, `dplyr`, or one of the SQL packages will provide better performance.

Comment: does this work correctly for you? I'm getting warnings in `mapply`. `aggregate` is most likely your major bottleneck followed by all the subsetting. I would switch to dplyr

Comment: @rawr did you just said... (and I quote) "I would switch to **dplyr**"?

Comment: @rawr, the warnings come from the aggregate line trying to divide factors by each other. This isn't an issue in my actual formula (I don't think...).

Comment: @r2evans I keep running across data.table in the googling that I've done. I haven't used it before, but perhaps I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @DavidArenburg eek I thought today was April Fool's day!

Comment: @rawr Good catch, completely forgot about that. You had me worried for a minute there.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform

```
scores <- aggregate(score ~ student, data=subsetdf,sum)/aggregate(points.possible ~ student, data=subsetdf, sum)
```

the result is not strictly numeric, the result is a data frame (for example, for `a.id = 'a1', i.id = 'i1'`):

```
> aggregate(score ~ student, data=subsetdf,sum)
      student score
1      s1     3
2      s2     2
3      s3     3
4      s4     2
```

So when you divide the two, the result of `'s1'/'s1'` is not numeric and throws a warning.

1. There is no need to create `correct` and `wrong`. Treat the value of that column as an indicator to tell you whether the student was right or wrong.

Instead, do the following:

```
scores <- aggregate(subsetdf[,c('score', 'points.possible')], by = list(subsetdf$student), sum)
names(scores) <- c('student', 'score','points.possible')
scores$avg.score <- scores$score/scores$points.possible
```

I would do the same for `x.0` and `x.1`. If you create a subset by `i.id` and then aggregate that subset of the dataframe, this should also save you a few steps.
The fact that you are checking for each student whether or not they are in `correct` or `wrong` twice (for `score` and `points.possible`) is also pretty expensive.